# How can I sort a list of Employees by the SortOrder of their Roles?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to sort a list of employees which can have any number of different roles. The roles themselves are sorted by the `SortOrder` property, and I want the employees to be sorted according to the top sorted of all the roles that are assigned to them.

E.g.:

```
SortOrder - Role
1 - "Manager"
2 - "Graphics designer"
3 - "Server-tech-guy"
4 - "Web developer"
5 - "Coffee Machine manager"
```

An employee could be both graphics designer and manage the coffee machine. In that case, I only want to use the `SortOrder` of the role "Graphics designer" when sorting the list of employees.

Here are my models:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public double EmploymentPercentage { get; set; }
    public double HourlyWage { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeRole> EmployeeRoles { get; set; }
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
}
```

This is the query I have so far:

```
List<Employee> employees = await db.Employees
    .Include(er => er.EmployeeRoles)
        .ThenInclude(r => r.Role)
    .Where(b => b.Branch.Id == BranchId)
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.EmployeeRoles.Min(s => s.Role.SortOrder))
        .ThenByDescending(p => p.EmploymentPercentage)
            .ThenBy(n => n.LastName)
    .ToListAsync();
```

In this query I tried to find the role with the lowest `SortOrder`-number for each employee (`.Min(s => s.Role.SortOrder)`, but it's not doing what I expected. I'm getting

> InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements.

Comment: Create an array  string[] sortOrder = {"Manager","Graphics designer","Server-tech-guy","Web developer","Coffee Machine manager"};  The get the indexof sort order  Orderby(r => sortOrder.IndexOf(r.EmployeeRoles))

Comment: the only method in your example, which can throw this exception is `Min()`. Seems some Employees have no Roles?

Comment: @python_kaa Yes, that's exactly the case. See accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non nullable overloads of `Min` and `Max` methods throw exception when the source sequence is empty (for instance if you have some `Employee` without assigned `Role`s).

However the nullable overloads do not throw exception, but simply return `null`. Hence the solution is to promote the non nullable type to the corresponding nullable type. Additionally `??` operator can be used to designate a special value for that case.

In your case it can be something like this:

```
.OrderByDescending(r => r.EmployeeRoles.Min(s => (int?)s.Role.SortOrder) ?? 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's doing exactly what I need. Though I found out that what I wanted was `OrderBy`, not `OrderByDescending`. Don't know why I had that. So then I had to change the 0 to an arbitrary high number, like so: `.OrderBy(r => r.EmployeeRoles.Min(s => (int?)s.Role.SortOrder) ?? 999999)`.